# How to see the questions that gave you a Unsung Hero badge?

Tags: support, badges

I'm just curious:

[image]

How can I see the questions that gave me that badge?

Comment: This is a valid support question people, not sure why this is being downvoted.

Comment: should this question be migrated to [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)?

Comment: @chharvey: no, such questions are perfectly on topic here too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [*does not show any research effort*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: what has that got to do with wether or not this should be migrated to Meta.SE? We don't expect users to know about that site.

Comment: Nothing. It addresses "*not sure why this is being downvoted*".

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i

Comment: Why aren't the posts listed on the badge page like with Nice Answer / Nice Question / Reversal / Guru / etc. / etc. ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use search; look for 0-score accepted answers by you that are at least 10 days old, so `user:me is:a isaccepted:1 score:0 created:..10d`. You have [11 matching answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4227915+is%3aa+isaccepted%3a1+score%3a0+created%3a..10d), out of [39 accepted answers older than 10 days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4227915+is%3aa+isaccepted%3a1+created%3a..10d), giving you both criteria (more than 10 and at least 25%).

You'll have to manually subtract self-answers (which are excluded from the badge) if you have any, we currently cannot select answers based on who asked the associated question.

Comment: After restricting by date, it's either these 11: [user:4227915 isaccepted:1 score:0 created:..10d](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4227915+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0+created%3A..10d) or these 10:  [user:4227915 isaccepted:1 score:0 created:..11d](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4227915+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0+created%3A..11d), depending on how the equality cases are handled.

Comment: @NormalHuman: ah, I forgot about the ability to use relative dates! I think `10d` should do, as that fits with the *more than 10* criteria.

Comment: @NormalHuman: [user:me isaccepted:1 score:0 created:..10d](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0+created%3A..10d) is a lot more convenient than the SEDE query I've been using, for sure!

Comment: One thing to be aware of, wont these include answers that were marked as correct by yourself?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: yes, the search will include self-answers, that's harder to exclude.

Comment: Why `created`? Doesn't seems to be very useful to select the 10 or 25%.

Comment: @Braiam: To ensure the accepted answers are still at 0 only answers at least 10 days old are considered for the badge.

Comment: @NormalHuman that query returns self-answers, which I don't think count for the Unsung Hero badge.

Comment: @JAL: you cannot filter out self-answers with a search.