# Average "unsung rate" on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer

After checking [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302081/how-to-see-the-questions-that-gave-you-a-unsung-hero-badge) and the comments I checked my own ["unsung rate"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i) (~26%).

Is it possible to know the average "unsung rate" in Stack Overflow? Maybe of the top 5% of the users only (so the big answerers are mainly included)?

How much is that value?

What about unsung rate by tags (top 20~ tags for example)?

How much variation is there between tops answerers in each tag?

Comment: Pretty hard to quantify, the median reputation of SO users is only 21.  Not a lot of singing going on.  You would have to first carve out some subset of users that could even get close to having a representable number.  Try [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6607/the-true-unsung-heros) to compare yourself.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I ask to only include just a subset of the users (maybe classified by reputation? >3000 rep users only ?) @HansPassant

Comment: Well, tinker with that query to set your own standard.

Comment: @HansPassant I have absolutely no idea whatsoever how to do that, but I'll try a bit ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I focus on users having more than 10000 rep, the mean "unsung rate" is 0.117808605. (see [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/698743/unsung-rate)).

A breakup:

```
Ratio   Percentile
0.02    10
0.05    20
0.07    30
0.09    40
0.11    50
0.13    60
0.15    70
0.18    80
0.22    90
0.26    95
0.3587  99
```

The users near the top [of this other SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/698745/the-true-unsung-heros) are the "True Unsung Heroes"; the top user has 134/177 of his accepted answers on a zero score.

Near the bottom are the "sung" users; the most sung user has had 1000/1013 accepted answers on a non-zero score.

As you would imagine the unsungness ratio decreases as user reputation increases:

```
Avg Ratio   Reputation          Rep Percentile
0.13        10000 to 12842      0-25
0.12        12842 to 17917      25-50
0.11        17917 to 30869      50-75
0.10        30869 to 57942      75-90
0.09        57942 to 91502      90-95
0.08        91502 to 231474     95-99
0.07        231474 to 959896    99-
```

Breaking this down by tags having more than 1000 answers ([this SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/698910/unsung-rate-by-tag?ScoreThreshold=1000&opt.textResults=true)) tells us that the most unsung tags are:

```
Tagname                   Non zero score answers Zero score answers Total  Ratio 
------------------------- ---------------------- ------------------ ------ ----- 
sharepoint-2013           664                    574                1238   0.46  
wso2                      1625                   1110               2735   0.41  
server                    2336                   1471               3807   0.39  
slideshow                 857                    541                1398   0.39  
crystal-reports           2450                   1502               3952   0.38  
ibm-mobilefirst           1729                   1049               2778   0.38  
ajaxcontroltoolkit        660                    409                1069   0.38  
sharepoint-2010           2343                   1381               3724   0.37  
navbar                    936                    561                1497   0.37  
gallery                   919                    550                1469   0.37
```

And the most "sung" users reply to questions about:

```
Tagname                   Non zero score answers Zero score answers Total  Ratio 
------------------------- ---------------------- ------------------ ------ ----- 
haskell                   23226                  872                24098  0.04  
common-lisp               2863                   134                2997   0.04  
java-stream               2330                   100                2430   0.04  
julia-lang                1991                   84                 2075   0.04  
d                         1690                   73                 1763   0.04  
sse                       998                    43                 1041   0.04  
f#                        8435                   301                8736   0.03  
rust                      5119                   157                5276   0.03  
language-lawyer           2193                   44                 2237   0.02  
monads                    1743                   43                 1786   0.02
```

Finally, looking at what I believe are the [Top 40 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/698932/unsung-rate-by-tag?ScoreThreshold=56700):

```
Tagname        Non zero score answers Zero score answers Total      Ratio 
-------------- ---------------------- ------------------ ------     ----- 
excel          42498                  17881              60379      0.3   
android        329388                 132059             461447     0.29  
ajax           61922                  24836              86758      0.29  
vb.net         43130                  17138              60268      0.28  
php            435733                 150922             586655     0.26  
mysql          194442                 67836              262278     0.26  
xml            67766                  23354              91120      0.26  
html           286279                 95375              381654     0.25  
asp.net        128912                 43547              172459     0.25  
json           83294                  28353              111647     0.25  
jquery         378130                 118924             497054     0.24  
css            215830                 66585              282415     0.24  
ios            198550                 63040              261590     0.24  
angularjs      87401                  27855              115256     0.24  
swift          60081                  18731              78812      0.24  
database       53683                  16915              70598      0.24  
xcode          46480                  14944              61424      0.24  
javascript     612152                 180367             792519     0.23  
ruby-on-rails  126177                 36851              163028     0.23  
node.js        66623                  20106              86729      0.23  
asp.net-mvc    70521                  19788              90309      0.22  
wpf            61427                  17084              78511      0.22  
java           529957                 141836             671793     0.21  
objective-c    130226                 34526              164752     0.21  
arrays         117431                 30770              148201     0.21  
iphone         102480                 27939              130419     0.21  
django         65584                  17228              82812      0.21  
sql            193886                 48746              242632     0.2   
sql-server     95512                  24086              119598     0.2   
c#             530382                 124511             654893     0.19  
linux          63845                  13905              77750      0.18  
python         368489                 77598              446087     0.17  
ruby           95009                  19738              114747     0.17  
.net           136175                 23809              159984     0.15  
regex          104559                 18742              123301     0.15  
r              94458                  16079              110537     0.15  
string         65729                  11619              77348      0.15  
multithreading 48283                  8699               56982      0.15  
c++            273217                 42736              315953     0.14  
c              132544                 20633              153177     0.13
```

Breaking this across sites, with no minimum user/question thresholds, the ratios are:

[stackoverflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.177

[superuser](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.1378

[askubuntu](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.1509

[english](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.0765

[serverfault](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.1246

[unix](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.0716

[gaming](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.0259

[apple](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/698968/unsung-rate) = 0.1077

Comment: WOW great answer! Also ultimately this means that I am very unsung for SO terms (or I suck at answering, which is definitely an option :P )

Comment: Well, yes... for a man of your reputation. For the site as a whole (18.4 vs 17.7) percent you're pretty near the mean.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just realized how old this question was. I had 26 back the, 18 now. I've learned a lesson somewhere in the way, not sure which one, not sure when.